# "Executable File" for node.js in Github

Tags: node.js, github, shebang

Github is supposed to say `"Executable File"` in place of `** lines(** sloc)`
after putting the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` in. Instead it puts lines and SLOC. How can I make it say `"Executable File"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in a script doesn't alone make the file "executable." It's just an instruction for how to execute the file when and if it is.

You'll need to change the file's mode to permit execution.

[On Linux/Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod):

```
chmod +x {file}
```

[On Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454764/how-to-chmod-0777-a-file-and-commit-as-is-to-git-on-windows):

```
git update-index --chmod=+x {file}
```

---

You can also review the file's mode with `ls-files --stage`:

```
# before chmod
git ls-files --stage
100644 {commit} {length} {name}

# after chmod
git ls-files --stage
100755 {commit} {length} {name}
```